# Multiple entry points (routes) as single request with multiple queries?

Tags: relayjs

I want to start using Relay in my application but it can be done only part by part. This means that I will end up with several applications embedded inside page each with its own entry point. This way every entry point will be creating its own graphql query and will send it as separate request which obviously is not what I want to achieve.

Is there any possibility to have multiple entry points that will be collected and send to server as one request with multiple root queries? If not maybe there is a workaround that can be applied? Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment the `Relay.RootContainer` *is* the unit of abstraction for grouping components together and dealing with their collective data-fetching requirements as a single unit.

You can nest non-Relay components inside of Relay ones, so you may be able to avoid issuing multiple, independent requests from multiple `RootContainer`s by creating a single container that comprises a Relay component with other non-Relay parts of the UI nested inside.

Comment: What I would expect is to have all `RootContainer`s using same `Route` of course to be merged into one request. Looks like it is the way it should be handled and gives you extreme flexibility. 



I guess it shouldn't be much problem because both `RootContainer` will be operating on fragments with same Type so there is only a need to create new request from two and put that fragments as childs of your root query.

Comment: Unfortunately the `Route` terminology is a little confusing because it overloads a term that many associate with URLs. A Relay Route is really just a query config (a name, some queries, and some param definitions), so you shouldn't necessarily expect that multiple `RootContainer`s share the same query config, even if they are all mounted within the same view (and share a top-level URL). We definitely want to improve the naming here.

Comment: Its not about naming. When I have multiple `RootContainer`s that are using same top level resource (in this case its named `Route` but that doesn't matter because all of them have same query config!) it seems quite obvious that you want to fetch data for them as one request and that is what I want to describe here.

Answer (score 0):

From the ‘heinous hack’ department: you could create a custom network layer that batches up any calls to `sendQueries()`, sends them to the server in a single request, and resolves the promises with the correct part of the response.

See also: http://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/guides-network-layer.html#custom-network-layers